# GML to GeoJSON JavaScript parser

Tags: javascript, geojson, gml

Is there a JavaScript parser to obtain GeoJSON from GML?

I have found only Python and OGR solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the OpenLayers Format readers and writers.

GML reader here
http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/GML-js.html

GeoJSON writer here
http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON-js.html

May be overkill to just convert from GML to GeoJSON, but OpenLayers API are widely used and tested, and also easy to extend.

Also, you could create a small OpenLayers build with just those classes and their dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think this project may helps you.
https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas.

It is based on Node.js environment. 
but if you want to make use of it in client side, it is possible with Browserify(http://browserify.org/)

Comment: Any advice on using jsonix and ogc-schemas, without running a bit of Java ?