# Is it possible to convert GML to GeoJSON

Tags: geoserver, geojson, gml

This is an example generated by GeoServer.

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ne="https://www.naturalearthdata.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd https://www.naturalearthdata.com http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ne/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=ne%3Amy_dist">
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
</gml:boundedBy>
<gml:featureMember>
<ne:my_dist fid="63f4bcd39256965f103900c9">
<ne:geometry>
<gml:MultiPolygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
<gml:polygonMember>
<gml:Polygon>
<gml:outerBoundaryIs>
<gml:LinearRing>
<gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">70.954883,32.871172 70.874135,32.878455 70.733054,32.796735 70.685352,32.842473 70.535514,32.806446 70.519034,32.760444 70.400101,32.72879 70.372559,32.707602 70.3857,32.765611 70.409241,32.86972 70.411217,32.87281 70.524803,33.054539 70.730301,33.059513 70.795443,33.095975 70.84123,33.02656 70.915501,33.01377 70.954883,32.871172</gml:coordinates>
</gml:LinearRing>
</gml:outerBoundaryIs>
</gml:Polygon>
</gml:polygonMember>
</gml:MultiPolygon>
</ne:geometry>
<ne:properties.cartodb_id>65</ne:properties.cartodb_id>
<ne:properties.objectid>67</ne:properties.objectid>
<ne:properties.shape_leng>2.103026</ne:properties.shape_leng>
<ne:properties.district_agency>Bannu</ne:properties.district_agency>
<ne:type>Feature</ne:type>
<ne:properties.created_at>2015-07-06T09:49:19Z</ne:properties.created_at>
<ne:properties.province_territory>Khyber Pakhtunkhwa</ne:properties.province_territory>
<ne:properties.updated_at>2015-07-06T09:49:19Z</ne:properties.updated_at>
<ne:properties.districts>BannuDDDD</ne:properties.districts>
<ne:_id>63f4bcd39256965f103900c9</ne:_id>
<ne:properties.shape_area>0.116758</ne:properties.shape_area>
<ne:properties.status>District</ne:properties.status>
</ne:my_dist>
</gml:featureMember>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

I want it to be displayed in GeoJSON format. Is it possible to do it programmatically?

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[70.954883,32.871172],[70.874135,32.878455],[70.733054,32.796735],[70.685352,32.842473],[70.535514,32.806446],[70.519034,32.760444],[70.400101,32.72879],[70.372559,32.707602],[70.3857,32.765611],[70.409241,32.86972],[70.411217,32.87281],[70.524803,33.054539],[70.730301,33.059513],[70.795443,33.095975],[70.84123,33.02656],[70.915501,33.01377],[70.954883,32.871172]]]]},"properties":{"objectid":67,"province_territory":"Khyber Pakhtunkhwa","districts":"Bannu","shape_leng":2.103026,"shape_area":0.116758,"district_agency":"Bannu","status":"District","cartodb_id":65,"created_at":"2015-07-06T09:49:19Z","updated_at":"2015-07-06T09:49:19Z"}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GML to GeoJSON JavaScript parser](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191372/gml-to-geojson-javascript-parser)

Comment: why not just ask GeoServer for GeoJSON output? https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html